# Strange object invisibility with no edit mode

Tags: objects

I've been following a tutorial from Youtube on how to create a character from scratch, but I've come across a bizarre problem. I've been following step by step all the way, but somehow I've managed to make a character's eyes and teeth disappear even when they're supposed to be visible.

[image: Character Missing Eyes]

As you can see, the eyes ARE selected and the Eye Icon is on meaning they should be visible. I've heard something about layers, but after checking it over all my objects are on the same layer, but the dot on the bottom is grey instead of yellow. I can't seem to be in any other mode than Object Mode with them, plus even when I use 'View- View Selected', the viewport doesn't move, so it's not like I've moved them elsewhere and can't find them.

[image: Character Missing Eyes Hair Selected]

In this picture all I've done is select the 'Hair' object to compare the settings between them. As you can see, the layer dot is yellow, the translation icon is on the object and I can go into all the modes. I'm still new to Blender and am very, very confused where my eyes and teeth have gone. Help please??

I'm using Blender 2.78

Comment: Maybe you hide them inadvertently. Try pressing ALT + "H".

Comment: One of the first things I tried, it didn't work at the time. :/ As an update, I just reloaded the scene and the eyes are there again, but I wanna make sure that I can still undo it if it ever happens again.